# (Domino Notes)How to move documents from the original NSF to another NSF?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

There are two NSF on the server, and there are many documents in the two NSF.

When I divide a case in NSF A to a specific member, is there a way to move the document to NSF B?

When dividing a case into a specific member, there is a field in the document to display the name of the member.

If it is feasible, how is it achieved? Is it copied or moved?

Is it possible to share the method?

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? Show us some code that you have problems with

Comment: Check out the CopyAllItems method of the NotesDocument class.

Comment: How many is "many" documents? Why would you want to use multiple dbs? There are at least 4 ways to move documents from one db to another...

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten I haven't started trying to write the code, just want to ask if anyone has done it...

Comment: @Duston Thanks!I trying this class now. I hope it can be work.

Comment: @D.Bugger There are hundreds of documents in each DB. Different units for different needs, so there are multiple DBs.

Comment: "so there are..." ?  Why not everything in one database, if the design of all related databases is identical? If you want some people not to see certain documents, isn't that more a question of user rights? You can assign rights to (groups of) people, and make documents invisible to them if you want to. Just asking...

Comment: @D.Bugger Sorry....this is our company's rule. I don't know why not everything in one database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CopyToDatabase method of the Document class. Here's a simplified LotusScript example:

```
Dim targetDb As New NotesDatabase("", "path/target.nsf")
Call doc.CopyToDatabase(targetDb)
```

In order to complete the 'move' operation, you just need to delete the source document afterwards:

```
Call doc.Remove(True)
```

Comment: This way can achieve me in need, but this is "copy" not "move". Can any class be "move" or "delete" the document?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you how to combine CopyToDatabase with Remove in order to do your desired move operation

Comment: Would it be possible to create the document directly in the target database, so there is no need to move it? Again, just asking... ;-)

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten If the user's access control didn't have to remove permission, this removed code can't be work, right?